# split method in sub methods with python

Tags: python, refactoring

I have a little app that text reads from images in pdf.

And then filtering from the extracted text some subtext. like this:

```
apples_royal_gala = 'Appels Royal Gala 13kg 60/65 Generica PL Klasse I'
ananas_crownless = 'Ananas Crownless 14kg 10 Sweet CR Klasse I'
peen_waspeen = 'Peen Waspeen 14x1lkg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I'
```

But I try now to refactor this long method in some sub methods.

So I try it like this:

```
import io
from tracemalloc import start
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
from wand.image import Image as wi
import re

apples_royal_gala = 'Appels Royal Gala 13kg 60/65 Generica PL Klasse I'
ananas_crownless = 'Ananas Crownless 14kg 10 Sweet CR Klasse I'
peen_waspeen = 'Peen Waspeen 14x1lkg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I'


def make_pattern(substr):
    return r"(?<=" + substr + r").*?(?P<number>[0-9,.]*)\n"


def reading_text_from_pdf():
    pdfFile = wi(filename="C:\\Users\\engel\\Documents\\python\\docs\\fixedPDF.pdf", resolution=300)
    text_factuur_verdi = []

    image = pdfFile.convert('jpeg')
    imageBlobs = []
    for img in image.sequence:
        imgPage = wi(image=img)
    imageBlobs.append(imgPage.make_blob('jpeg'))

    for imgBlob in imageBlobs:
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgBlob))
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng')
        text_factuur_verdi.append(text)
        extracting_text_from_pdf()


def extracting_text_from_pdf(text):
    substring_apples = re.findall(make_pattern(apples_royal_gala), text)
    substring_ananas = re.findall(make_pattern(ananas_crownless), text)
    substring_peen_waspeen = re.findall(make_pattern(peen_waspeen), text)

    print(substring_ananas[0]) if len(substring_ananas) > 0 else 'null'
    print(substring_apples[0]) if len(substring_apples) > 0 else 'null'
    print(substring_peen_waspeen[0]) if len(substring_peen_waspeen) > 0 else 'null'
```

oke,

I try it like this:

```
apples_royal_gala = 'Appels Royal Gala 13kg 60/65 Generica PL Klasse I'
ananas_crownless = 'Ananas Crownless 14kg 10 Sweet CR Klasse I'
peen_waspeen = 'Peen Waspeen 14x1lkg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I'


def make_pattern(substr):
    return r"(?<=" + substr + r").*?(?P<number>[0-9,.]*)\n"
def reading_text_from_pdf():

    pdfFile = wi(
        filename="C:\\Users\\engel\\Documents\\python\\docs\\fixedPDF.pdf", resolution=300)
    text_factuur_verdi = []
    

    image = pdfFile.convert('jpeg')
    imageBlobs = []
    for img in image.sequence:
        imgPage = wi(image=img)
    imageBlobs.append(imgPage.make_blob('jpeg'))

    for imgBlob in imageBlobs:
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgBlob))
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng')
        text_factuur_verdi.append(text)
        extracting_sub_text_from_main_text(text)
      
        
def extracting_sub_text_from_main_text(text):    
    substring_apples = re.findall(make_pattern(apples_royal_gala), text)
    substring_ananas = re.findall(make_pattern(ananas_crownless), text)
    substring_peen_waspeen = re.findall(make_pattern(peen_waspeen), text)
    print(substring_ananas[0]) if len(substring_ananas) > 0 else 'null'
    print(substring_apples[0]) if len(substring_apples) > 0 else 'null'
    print(substring_peen_waspeen[0]) if len(substring_peen_waspeen) > 0 else 'null'
    
print(reading_text_from_pdf())
```

But ofcourse the method

```
extracting_sub_text_from_main_text
```

is none.

But how to pas the text tot the method?

Thank you

I had it like this:

```
import io
from tracemalloc import start
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
from wand.image import Image as wi
import re


def make_pattern(substr):
    return r"(?<=" + substr + r").*?(?P<number>[0-9,.]*)\n"


pdfFile = wi(
    filename="C:\\Users\\engel\\Documents\\python\\docs\\fixedPDF.pdf", resolution=300)

text_factuur_verdi = []
apples_royal_gala = 'Appels Royal Gala 13kg 60/65 Generica PL Klasse I'
ananas_crownless = 'Ananas Crownless 14kg 10 Sweet CR Klasse I'
peen_waspeen = 'Peen Waspeen 14x1lkg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I'


image = pdfFile.convert('jpeg')
imageBlobs = []

for img in image.sequence:
    imgPage = wi(image=img)
    imageBlobs.append(imgPage.make_blob('jpeg'))

    for imgBlob in imageBlobs:
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgBlob))
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng')
        text_factuur_verdi.append(text)
        substring_apples = re.findall(make_pattern(apples_royal_gala), text)
        substring_ananas = re.findall(make_pattern(ananas_crownless), text)
        substring_peen_waspeen = re.findall(make_pattern(peen_waspeen), text)

    print(substring_ananas[0]) if len(substring_ananas) > 0 else 'null'
    print(substring_apples[0]) if len(substring_apples) > 0 else 'null'
    print(substring_peen_waspeen[0]) if len(
        substring_peen_waspeen) > 0 else 'null'
```

And this works. But of course this has to be splitted in several methods.

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to know if and how you can better structure your code?

Comment: So my question is how to refactor this example?

Comment: But do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Your problem is, that if you exectue the code you only get the output `None`, but you want to get all matches of your substrings with the pdf. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: But how to pass text to the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved like this:

```
pdfFile = wi(filename="C:\\Users\\engel\\Documents\\python\\docs\\fixedPDF.pdf", resolution=300)
text_factuur_verdi = []
apples_royal_gala = 'Appels Royal Gala 13kg 60/65 Generica PL Klasse I'
ananas_crownless = 'Ananas Crownless 14kg 10 Sweet CR Klasse I'
peen_waspeen = 'Peen Waspeen 14x1lkg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I'

def make_pattern(substr):
    return r"(?<=" + substr + r").*?(?P<number>[0-9,.]*)\n"


def get_text_from_image(): 
    
    image = pdfFile.convert('jpeg')
   
    imageBlobs = []
    
    for img in image.sequence:
        imgPage = wi(image=img)
        imageBlobs.append(imgPage.make_blob('jpeg'))

    for imgBlob in imageBlobs:        
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgBlob))
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng')
        text_factuur_verdi.append(text)       

    return text_factuur_verdi
        
def filterAnanas():
    get_text_from_image()        
    return re.findall(make_pattern(ananas_crownless), text_factuur_verdi[0])


if ananas_crownless: print(filterAnanas())
```

Answer (score 0):

A function which returns no values (contains no `return` statements), will always return `None` in python.

Because of that behavior your last line `print(reading_text_from_pdf())` will always print `None`, as long `reading_text_from_pdf` doesn´t return any values.

But to achieve your goal, it is not necessary to change the function `reading_text_from_pdf`.

The function `extracting_sub_text_from_main_text` takes the extracted text from the pdf and searches for the substrings. The three following lines print the matches, but only if you found at least one. If the matcher didn´t find any matches nothing will happen, because of a wrong bracket placement. I think you actually want following lines:

```
def extracting_sub_text_from_main_text(text):    
    ...
    print(substring_ananas[0] if len(substring_ananas) > 0 else 'null')
    print(substring_apples[0]) if len(substring_apples) > 0 else 'null')
    print(substring_peen_waspeen[0] if len(substring_peen_waspeen) > 0 else 'null')
```

But I am guessing, that this will not fix your problem. I am pretty sure that this will only result in three `null` strings per image, because based on your code and comments I am pretty sure that the matcher doesn´t find the pattern in the extracted text.

In **conclusion** your problem is not the passing of the text to the function `extracting_sub_text_from_main_text`, it is either a faulty pattern or your text extraction is inaccurate. I suggest to inspect your extracted text and check your regex with the extracted text on [regex101](https://regex101.com/) (make sure to set the flavor to python).

If you have further questions, I am happy to help you. :)

**EDIT** (based on updated question):
In both code samples are indents which don´t make sense. In the following code block I will update your original code:

```py
...

for img in image.sequence:
    ...

for imgBlob in imageBlobs:  # in the old code imageBlobs was iterated multiple times
    ...
    # following code should be in the loop, to output every match     
    print(substring_ananas[0]) if len(substring_ananas) > 0 else 'null'
    print(substring_apples[0]) if len(substring_apples) > 0 else 'null'
    print(substring_peen_waspeen[0]) if len(substring_peen_waspeen) > 0 else 'null'
```

Than the reformated code:

```py
...
    
def reading_text_from_pdf():
    ...

    for img in image.sequence:
        ...
        imageBlobs.append(imgPage.make_blob('jpeg'))  # in the old code only the last page was added
...
```